# Convert AnyObject / NSDictionary (JSON) to string?

Tags: ios, json, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm calling the Facebook graph for the list of friends and I want to send it as a parameter to a javascript function in my `UIWebView`.

My problem is I can't turn the response (`AnyObject` / `NSDictionary`) to a normal simple `String`.

In this example I want the complete response to be sent to the JavaScript method as a string which I will use internally.

(Currently I'm getting an empty `String` and every attempt I've made so far failed)

```
                let graphFriendsRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: nil)
            graphFriendsRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if ((error) != nil)
                {
                    // Process error
                    println("Error: \(error)")
                }
                else
                {
                    println("fetched friends: \(result)")

                    let data:NSDictionary=result as! NSDictionary


                    var jsmethod = NSString(format:"setusers('%@')",data) as String
                    self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsmethod)


                }
            })
```

Comment: Are you sure `data` is a valid NSDictionary? Add `println(data)` after the declaration, or better, add a breakpoint on the line `var jsmethod...` then inspect the contents of `data`. Because your line  `var jsmethod...` should work.

Comment: Now it seems to work! (I was sure it was empty earlier) but there is a new problem: the string has \n in it so I can't use JSON.stringify(data) on the javascript side. How can I "clean" the string?

Answer (score 0):

Following what you said in the comments, I think you should generate JSON instead of manipulating the string itself.

You receive JSON in your Swift app, and you want JSON in your JavaScript: no need to use "cleaned" strings.

```
// Bogus data for example: an array with a dictionary
let exampleString = "[{\"fields\": {\"key1\": 42}}]" // it would be `jsmethod` for you
let exampleStringData = exampleString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
// Cocoa object from data
var arrayFromData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(exampleStringData!, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSArray
// JSON from the object
var toJS = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(arrayFromData, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)
```

Then send this real JSON to your JavaScript.

**EDIT:**

Are you talking about sanitizing a string like with URLs and spaces by any chance? If yes, you can do it like this (many options):

```
let sanitized = jsmethod.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: I need to create the string setusers(JSON AS STRING) - how can I do that with the toJS (which is pure JSON - without the JS function name and is not a string) ?

Comment: You have all you need. :) If you want to send a string, do it: you already have it. If your JS needs a cleaner string, then it's another question. But the real thing is: JSON is a format *created for this*. You don't make a string from an object then send it only to change it back into JSON once received: you have an object, transform it into JSON then send the JSON. Then change it into an object on the JS side.

Comment: I say "If your JS needs a cleaner string, then it's another question." because you can't just remove the line feeds. What if your data contains a legitimate "\n" somewhere? You shouldn't change your data. Just change the format. And since you receive JSON, just send JSON. :)

Comment: well... how can I send your toJS to the javascript?  I need to make it a "string" (sent as a parameter to the js method). problem #1: my jsmethod is not JSON - its a javascript function call with json as string as param...

Comment: Let me paraphrase myself again: *If you want to send a string, do it: you already have it (`jsmethod`). If your JS needs a string without line feeds for some reason, then it's another question (see my previous comment). But you should use JSON anyway.* :)